# jquery.editinplace inputs error when using jquery 1.10.2 (example below)

Tags: javascript, jquery, edit-in-place

I am using this library https://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/2jCWL/2/ (the function call is at the bottom of script section)

So my question is, how to make it work with `JQuery-1.10.2` or is it good to use `2 x JQuery` versions? (It works ok with `1.9.1` and lower than this versions of `JQuery`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higher versions than `jquery-1.9.1.js` does not support `$.browser`, solution to this problem is to include `jquery-migrate.js`, which does support `$.browser`